# Populate text boxes on dropdownlist select in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am new at asp.net. I have a dropdownlist which is populated in code behind. When I select any item from dropdownlist, it should populate two textbox and another dropdownlist according to data from table.

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" ID="dropDownExisting"></DropDownList><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPromotion" runat="server" Width="77px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox><br />
<asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownType" runat="server">
    <asp:ListItem>Monthly Newsleter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Webbinar Newsleter</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem>Annoucement</asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I want it to be done on client side. Where do I have to provide database connectivity? Do I require to use ajax control like update panel? Or javascript will work well? I want it on client side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got beautiful ans http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2(v=vs.100).aspx. This is exactly what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

Simply you can do this in DropDown `SelectedIndexChanged` Event

## [SelectedIndexChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedindexchanged%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**Edit**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="upDdlGoal" runat="server" UpdateMode="always">
    <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:DropDownList ID="drop1" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" EnableViewState="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="drop1_SelectedIndexChanged">                    
</asp:DropDownList>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostbackTrigger ControlID="drop1" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />  
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Code Behind:**

**VB:**

```
Protected Sub drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles ddlAddDepPlans.SelectedIndexChanged
    //Connectivity coding
End Sub
```

**C#:**

```
protected void drop1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    //Connectivity coding
}
```

Comment: I know about selectedindex changed but how can I display data from table in textboxes and where to provide connectivity?

Comment: write your connectivty code in selectedindex change event and populate

Comment: Than I think it will perform postback. I don't want that.

Comment: Please explain in detail. I am new at asp.net. Will have to use javascript even if I use update panel?

Comment: no need just write everything in selectedindex event and put update panel for dropdownlist

Comment: So I have to keep just the dropdownlist in update panel or all the four controls in update panel?

Answer (score 0):

Clients ide coding using JavaScript

**.aspx**

```
  <asp:DropDownList runat="server"  ID="dropDownExisting" ></asp:DropDownList><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPromotion" runat="server" Width="77px" ></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtSubject" runat="server" Width="288px"></asp:TextBox><br />
    <asp:DropDownList ID="dropDownType" runat="server">
        <asp:ListItem>Monthly Newsleter</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Webbinar Newsleter</asp:ListItem>
        <asp:ListItem>Annoucement</asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

**.cs**

```
  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            dropDownType.Attributes.Add("onChange", "return OnSelectedIndexChange();");
        }
```

**JavaScript:**

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
          function OnSelectedIndexChange() {
              var sel = document.getElementById("dropDownExisting");
              var text = sel.options.value;
              var out = document.getElementById("txtPromotion");
              out.value += text + "\n";


          }

    </script>
```

Comment: Where shell I provide database connectivity and where shell I declare that which column value to be displayed in which textbox? Where to write cs code?